What does it actually mean by "supporting ports of PHP extensions or features"?
I'm using Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit operating system, x64-based processor having Version 22H2 on my laptop.
Today I come across the below text on the website dedicated to supporting PHP on Microsoft Windows.

This site is dedicated to supporting PHP on Microsoft Windows. It also
supports ports of PHP extensions or features as well as providing
special builds for the various Windows architectures.

I didn't understand what does it actually mean by "supporting ports of PHP extensions or features"?
Can someone please help me understand this with some suitable example?
Thanks in advance.


in this case, 'port' means re-written in full or part to work in another enviroment. ie code written for unix ported to windows.

It means supporting PHP extensions/features which have been "ported" to run on Windows - i.e. fully or partially re-written from the original version, which would generally be aimed at Linux/Unix systems
